# Removing null values from array and getting it from the method in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to remove null values from an array, and returning them to do some other stuff with the new values. However, I'm confused about how to get the updated array.

This is the null removal code.

```
String[] removeNull(String[] nullArray) {
        int nullCounter = 0;
        //checking if any is null
        for(int i = 0; i < nullArray.length; i++) {
            if(nullArray[i]==null) {
                nullCounter++;
            }
        }
        String[] noNulls = new String[nullArray.length-nullCounter];
        if(nullCounter>0) {
        //make a non null array
            for(int i = 0, j = 0; i <noNulls.length; i++) {
                if(nullArray[i]!=null) {
                    noNulls[j] = nullArray[i];
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
    return noNulls; 
    }
```

I'm pretty sure that is already correct (Please correct me if I'm wrong). Then, I called it inside a constructor.

```
public theBoundary(String[] bounds){
   removeNull(bounds);
}
```

After I called removeNull(bounds), will the value of the new array be stored in the array bounds? Or will it be stored in the array noNull? I can't seem to find where the new values are stored.

Thank you, and please tell me if there are mistakes. I've been going around this for half an hour now.

Note: If possible, please don't give me answers that include importing something else. Vanilla Java would be preferred.

Comment: `removeNull` seems to be putting things in `noNulls` and returning it, but that returned value is ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`removeNull()` returns the array `noNulls`, created inside the method. Currently, in `theBoundary()`, you simply call `removeNull(bounds)`, but do not assign it to a variable. The newly created null-free array is created, not assigned, and immediately garbage collected.

If you wish to do something with your non-null-containing array (which I assume you do), do this:

```
public theBoundary(String[] bounds) {
    String[] withoutNulls = removeNull(bounds);

    doSomething(withoutNulls);  // whatever you need here
}
```

Note, unless you **really** have to use an array, consider using a `List` or even a `Stream`.

`List` example:

```
List<String> list = ...  // from somewhere else
list.removeIf(s -> s == null);

doSomething(list);
```

`Stream` example:

```
Stream<String> stream = ... //from somewhere else
stream.filter(s -> s != null);

doSomething(stream);
```

EDIT

Even if you do really need arrays, the following will also work:

```
String[] noNulls = (String[]) Arrays.stream(inputArray).filter(Objects::nonNull).toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any need to iterate the array twice!

You can instead use a stream on array and filter the indexes without that are NOT NULL.

Also, you can do this without needing to create the `removeNull` method, and do this directly in your `theBoundary` method.

Here is how your code will look like:

```
String[] arrayWithoutNull = Arrays.stream(bounds).filter(Objects::nonNull).toArray(String[]::new)
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean this?

```
public theBoundary(String[] bounds){
    String[] cleanedBounds = removeNull(bounds);
}
```

You are not doing it inplace so you need to assign it back to a new array